# c# find method overload from generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, methods, overloading

Consider the following methods:

```
public void foo(int a) {
   //do something with a
}

public void foo(ushort a) {
   //do something with a
}

public void foo<T>(Nullable<T> a) where T : struct {
     if (!a.HasValue) {
        return;
     }

     foo(a.Value); //find appropriate method based on type of a?
}
```

Is there any way to find the respective method to call based on the generic type of the parameter?  For example, if (T)a is an int, call the first method, if it's a ushort, call the second one.  If no such method exceeds, perhaps throw a runtime exception.

I've tried the following:

```
public void foo<T>(Nullable<T> a) where T : struct {
     if (!a.HasValue) {
        return;
     }
     switch(a.Value.GetType()) {
           case typeof(int): foo((int)a.Value); break;
           case typeof(ushort): foo((ushort)a.Value); break;
           //and so on
     }
}
```

But compiler doesn't like the cast ("Cannot convert type T to int");  Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can cast to `object` first, as in: `(int)(object)a.Value`.

Comment: Casting to object works as well.  I prefer dcastro's solution since I don't even have to use a switch statement and manually check each type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
public void foo<T>(Nullable<T> a) where T : struct {
 if (!a.HasValue) {
    return;
 }

 foo((dynamic)a.Value);
}
```

`a.Value`'s type will be resolved at runtime by using `dynamic`, and the appropriate overload will be called.

Comment: works perfectly!  Finally found an example where dynamic is useful.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: FYI, this will fail with a runtime exception if no suitable overload was found.